# React Native - Navigating to other screen from a component in Tab Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I'm having an issue with Navigation in React Native

My app has Tab Navigation(Main Screen). The first component has a list of articles. When an user taps on an articles. A detail article screen will appear overlay the Main Screen

In the First component. I created a `createStackNavigator` to open the detail article screen. But the problem is that it seems to replace the First component instead of overlaying the Main Screen

Here is the problem

[image]

But what I want is like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by hiding the tab navigator bar in specific pages of the stack navigator.

```
const FeedStack = createStackNavigator({
  FeedHome: FeedScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
});

FeedStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let tabBarVisible = true;
  if (navigation.state.index != 0) {
    tabBarVisible = false;
  }

  return {
   tabBarVisible,
  };
};
```

In this example `FeedStack` is the stack navigator you have inside you tab navigator. The if statement decides in which screens to show the tab navigator based on the id. In your case you want to show the navigator only on one screen. I suppose that the id of that screen is 0, but if it isn't you can just replace it with the id you want. The id of the screens is based on the order in which they are declared inside the stack navigator configuration.

Comment: I've just tried your code but it doesn't work. My News component is just an example but what all i want is any components in tab navigation can open another screen overlaying the Main Screen

Comment: You components inside your tab navigator cannot render on top of the tab bar if that is what you mean by overlaying. The only way to get that result is to hide the tab bar of the bottom navigator. The example above is from the documentation of react-navigation, and it has worked for me in the past. Here you can find the official documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-tab-navigator-contains-a-stack-and-you-want-to-hide-the-tab-bar-on-specific-screens

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation.  I understand it & it works for my app now